# Multidimentioanal arrays in JavaScript values not appending

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to add values in a multidimensional array in JavaScript, but it doesn't seem to work. I get "variable not defined" error in snippet but can't see any variable which is not defined.

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong here?

Many Thanks, 
Hassam

```js
var abc = "11:00, 11:10, 12:20,12:30";
var split = abc.split(",")
var limits = new Array();
 var alltimes = [[],[]];
//var split = ["11:00", "11:10", "12:20","12:30"];
var x = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < split.length -1 ; i++) {
            
             limits.push(split[i]);
            // alert(split.length );
             if(i%2 === 1) // If odd value
             {
                 alert(limits);
                 for (var j = 0;j<2; j++)
                 {
                //   alert(limits[j]);
                    alltimes[x][j] = limits[j];
                    
                 }
                 limits.length = 0;
                 x++;
             }
            //  alert(split.length + 2);
           //  
             
     }
             alert(alltimes);
 //           console.log(abc)
```

This is my JavaScript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.timepicker').click(function(){
        var ajaxurl = 'Ajax.php',
        data =  {'action': 'Hassam'};
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
        //    $('#timepicker').timepicker('option', 'disableTimeRanges', [abc]);
        var split = response.split(",");
        var x = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < split.length -1 ; i++) {

             limits.push(split[i]);
             alert(split.length );
             if(i%2 === 1) // If odd value
             {

                 for (var j = 0;j<2; j++)
                 {
                //   alert(limits[j]);
                    alltimes[x][j] = limits[j];

                 }
                 limits.length = 0;
                 x++;
             }
             alert(split.length + 2);
           //  

             }
             alert(alltimes);
 //           console.log(abc)
        });
```

Comment: Your code snippet returns "SyntaxError": Unexpected string"

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the line `var split = "11:00", "11:10", "12:00","12:10";`?

Comment: Hi, @StefanoNardo, Yes, it returns "unexpected string" - and i don't know why!

Comment: Hi, @Xufox, I want to make array of time values to disable range of times in jquery timepicker

Comment: @HassamMunir Then use array notation, not invalid syntax.

Comment: You probably want to do this : `var split = ["11:00", "11:10", "12:00","12:10"];`

Comment: Thankyou @Xufox, I have edited my snippet and added my JS code, I am actually getting comma delimited values from a string in "split" array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very simple solution to achieve what you want.

```js
var split = ["11:00", "11:10", "12:20", "12:30"];
var alltimes = [];
while (split.length) {
  alltimes.push(split.splice(0, 2));
}
console.log(alltimes);
```

Comment: Thank you @Alex, this is very elegant :)